# Unity3d and iPhone Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unity-game-engine

Hi I am very new to Unity3d and I have been writing in Objective-c for a year now. Is it possible to write Unity3d apps in Objective-c, and if so, how do I get started?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unity uses Mono and it languages are C#, JavaScript, Boo and C++ 
On iOS you can link Unity with native libs and frameworks. So you can use Objective-C in Unity code.

But it relates more to reusing Ad Network banner libs.

Game code is more convenient to write in C#, JavaScript

If you wish to develop Unity games then you have to use C#, JavaScript but you can still reuse some Objective-C code.

Answer (score -2):

This is not possible I guess.
Unity 3D works with Java and C++.
BUT you can write Unity 3D apps for iOS, compile for iOS :)

Comment: thanks :) but the problem is I only know C and Objective-c, I'm Not sure if I should take up java just for this, is it worth it or is there something similar to Unity which does use objective-c?

Comment: Java is easy. It has kinda the same syntax than C. I code in objective c and I learn Java in school, which is really easy. You can do alot with Unity 3D. You just have to think if ita worth doing it. I personally don't use Unity Anymore

Comment: This wrong as Unity does not support Java. It uses Mono languages C#, JavaScript, Boo

Comment: Unity does not support Java OR C++. http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3470971/Java-vs-JavaScript.htm http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?369278-C-C-which-main-differences

Comment: Unity Doesnot Support Java or C++ it supports javascript(unityscript), Boo and C#